# How can I forcibly block all the Internet traffic that doesn't go through a VPN to prevent accidental IP leak?

Tags: vpn, router, macos, data-leakage

I need to block all the Internet connections that don't go through a VPN server before they even get the chance to happen. How can I achieve this on Mac OS Big Sur? Mac OS doesn't seem to have any embedded tools that would allow me to do so (unlike Android, for example). Maybe there's a router firmware that would allow me to force a VPN-only connection on a specific device (does OpenVRT have such capabilities?)? Anything will do, but router configuration is preferable. I know that in order to prevent an IP-leak I must configure my browser very specifically (Javascript leakage prevention, or use Tor), but that's irrelevant in my case.

Comment: The common usage is to use a VPN client application that sets routes on the local machine to force all traffic to go through the VPN connection. Of course a privileged user can reset the routes to allow some destination to by-pass the VPN but *we cannot protect a system against its admin*.

Comment: But what if the VPN app doesn't support such functionality?

Comment: Use VPN app that supports system wide VPN. They make their own virtual route to route the traffic.

Comment: OpenWRT is Linux, and you can do what you need with iptables/routing, if you run the VPN client on there.